# Using sendmail command while using uuencode to send attachment

Tags: linux, shell, unix, centos

I am trying to send an email in a shell script with the sendmail command. I have successfully sent the email with a .txt file attached. Here is an example of my working code:

```
       echo "Please enter a valid email address:"
       read EMAIL
       uuencode results.txt results.txt | sendmail $EMAIL
```

However, when I try to add a subject and body, for example:

```
       uuencode results.txt results.txt | sendmail $EMAIL<<EOF
       subject: Log file from today

       Test
       EOF
```

The message sends properly but with no attachments. Any ideas? I'm a C++ and VB guy.

Thanks.

Comment: the second one is piping the uuencoded data to the sendmail command, but you're also basically overriding the piped data with the heredoc. in other words, "here's two sources of input, only pay attention to the second one (heredoc)"

Comment: I think I understand now with your explanation Marc and David's example. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put the result of the uuencode into a variable?  Assuming Bash:

```
ENCODED=`uuencode results.txt /dev/stdout`
echo "Please enter valid email address:"
read EMAIL
sendmail $EMAIL <<EOF
Subject: This is a test

Test file attached
--------------
$ENCODED
EOF
```